# What is the problem while running mongod.exe?

Tags: mongodb, server, command-prompt, atom-editor, community-server

[image: Command prompt showing this.]

shutting down is showing
what does this mean?
I m having problem in running mongod.exe

Comment: copy and paste the log result instead of taking a screenshot. It would be helpful for other people with the same problem to find your post.

Comment: I have created folder C:\data\dev.
Instead of C:\data\db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your data path.

1. make sure that the data path that you are using exists. in your case (C:/data/db/) if not then create the folders
2. use the following command: `mongod.exe --dbpath C:/data/db/`

Comment: sry i created dev folder instead of db. But thanks.